# Product price suddenly reduces when adding product to quote via admin backend, if Magento contains multiple currencies

Tags: backend, currency, multicurrency, admin-order-create

Scenario: Create order via admin backend

- Given there is a product with a price of 35.71
- And there is no discount available
- When you add this product to the quote
- Then the corresponding quote item has price 35.71

This user story is not valid, if your shop has more than one currency: Then the corresponding quote item has price 28.57, although all amounts are in the same currency.

What is even more strange: The error seems not to disappear, if I disable the second currency and even delete its currency rate.

Tax seems not to interfere with this issue, because I have it for both catalog prices including tax or not.

Can anyone confirm that? I checked two different stores today, running CE 1.7.0.2 and CE 1.9.2.1. Is it a known bug or did I miss something? How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: Indeed, that was a tax issue.

The product list before adding the product contains prices based on the tax of merchants location (e.g. 19%), while tax is recalculated for the customer when adding the product. Depending on your tax display settings, you will see different values including/excluding tax. This gets the more confusing if several currencies are used…